# razor @foreach issue with lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, razor

I try to pass a list into my view, but i get the following error :CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation in my view, at line @html.displayfor....

```
public class ColNameLink
{
    public string ColName { get; set; }
    public List<string> AvaiableDBcolumns { get; set; }
}


public class ViewModelListColumns 
{
    public List<ColNameLink> ColList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
        var columnNames = (from dc in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                select dc.ColumnName).ToList();

        var AvailLinks = new List<string>();
        AvailLinks.Add("FirstName");
        AvailLinks.Add("SurName");

        var viewModel = new ViewModelListColumns() { ColList = new List<ColNameLink>() };
        columnNames.ForEach(colName => viewModel.ColList.Add(new ColNameLink { ColName = colName, AvaiableDBcolumns = AvailLinks }));

        return View("ChooseColumns", viewModel);
```

View

```
    @Model uploabulk.ViewModels.ViewModelListColumns

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Column name</th>
        <th>Database column</th>
        <th>Include?</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var colList in Model)
    {
        foreach (var column in colList)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => column.ColName) </td>
                <td>Html.DropDownListFor("Selection", new SelectList(column.AvaiableDBcolumns, "AvailableDBcolumns"))</td>-->
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        }        
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want DropDownListFor and not DropDownList? The first argument to all of the `...For` methods in Razor is an expression (e.g. `m => m.AvailableDBcolumns`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code. First your view model is `uploabulk.ViewModels.ViewModelListColumns` and that's what you are passing to it here: `return View("ChooseColumns", viewModel);`.

But then inside your view you are attempting to write some `@foreach` loop over your `Model` which is impossible because you can only iterate over IEnumerable types.

So make sure that your view code is consistent with your view model:

```
@model uploabulk.ViewModels.ViewModelListColumns

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Column name</th>
        <th>Database column</th>
        <th>Include?</th>
    </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ColList.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ColList[i].ColName)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(
                    x => x.ColList[i].ColName, 
                    new SelectList(Model.ColList[i].AvaiableDBcolumns)
                )
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Very helpful. Now I get another error : "CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation" at the line " <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => colList.ColName) </td>"

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the `ColList` property in order to iterate it:

```
@foreach (var colList in Model.ColList)
```